# Calculating adjusted odds ratio

Tags: odds-ratio

I have also posted in http://www.talkstats.com/threads/adjusted-odds-ratio.77506/

I am in the process of teaching myself about odds ratios, adjusted odds ratios and modelling with regression for my MSc.

I am working with various publications but I have a question about how the statistics are calculated in the publication below (I am NOT challenging the calculations – just trying to follow how they are done)

Post‐disaster physical symptoms of firefighters and police officers: Role of types of exposure and post‐traumatic stress symptoms (wiley.com)
https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1348/135910707X198793

I am able to work out the unadjusted odds ratio in the table (Table 2) below (from the pub above).
However, looking at the adjusted odds ratio, it is adjusted for background characteristics. The background characteristics are in the table 2 down (Table 1) (from the pub above).

My questions are:
Am I correct in saying that I can’t calculate the adjusted odds ratio using the background characteristics given? eg I would need the Somatic symptoms split for male/female etc?
Am I correct in saying that that each adjusted odds ratio is adjusted for more than one background characteristic at once?
Is this related to modelling (ie forwards and backwards) in any way.
I have tried to find some worked examples but am struggling to find any. Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add complete references and links?

Comment: Apologies - thought I had done that!